# Getting notified when user run Forge application

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

to analysis who is using Forge app and how often is used, is it doable to get notified i.e. user (email) when login (BIM 360 hub) via autodesk account, and notify to (hardcoded) email, preferably email of developer (registered w/ forge app portal)? code sample or snippet will be very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forge itself does not provide any notification mechanism for this, but if you're developing your own Forge application, you could easily issue the notifications whenever your application receives a callback from the 3-legged OAuth workflow. For example, if you were following this Learn Forge tutorial: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels using .NET, you could modify the following controller method: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/blob/net/forgesample/Controllers/OAuthController.cs#L93-L103, to notify whoever needs to be notified.

Comment: thanks Petr, i downloaded latest NetCore codes from https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels, added the code snippet from https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/blob/net/forgesample/Controllers/OAuthController.cs#L93-L103, seems Request.CreateResponse() not working, besides, is there NodeJs code snippet?